# Vertical line scrolling across a picture

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, picturebox

I am making a sound sample player in C# and have a picture of the sample itself loaded into a PictureBox. The user presses the Play button and I would now like a vertical line scrolling across the picture as the sample plays.

I would like to use Winforms but am fairly new to this (and to C# graphics and animation in general) so would like to know the best approach.

Some of the sound sample pictures use fairly large resolutions and so the line animation technique would need to be efficient to ensure the line scrolls smoothly.

General ideas would be very welcome as would sample code snippets to point me in the right direction.

---

**EDIT:** Following Jimi's comments, I have added some sample code below. For brevity, certain aspects of the project are not shown (such as the sound sample playing) as at this stage I am only concerned about possible optimisation of the vertical line scrolling across the sample picture, which needs to be as fast/smooth as possible.

```
public partial class frmPlaySample : Form
{
    // We have set up a form in designer mode with a Play sample button (btnPlay), a picturebox (pictureBox1) and a Timer (timer1)

    public frmPlaySample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmPlaySample_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\SamplePicture.jpg");
        timer1.Interval = 17; // Timer Interval is set to 17 to approximate 60 frames per second.
    }

    int line = 0;

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        line=0;
        timer1.Enabled=true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.White), line,0,line,pictureBox1.Height);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate(); // If we wanted to, we could invalidate a narrow rectangle, but that would make things only slightly faster.
        line+=8; // This can be any amount. 8 is chosen arbitrarily.
        if(line>= pictureBox1.Width) { timer1.Enabled=false; line=0; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this is not that kind of question, that may be answered on this site (it is too broad). I think that you can find it by yourself with just a little googling for "winforms smooth progress bar". When you will choose a solution, write some code and still need help, you are welcome here.

Comment: Thank you for being polite considering I am a newbie here :)

Comment: I have done Googling but the two main problems I have encountered with examples given is: (a) progress bars fill up, which is not the same as a vertical line scroll, and (b) I need the line scrolling overlaid onto the sample picture, which would require layers or transparency of some description.

Admittedly my question is broad but I would be very happy to receive some general suggestions or even pointers.

Comment: Try breaking down the problem into smaller chunks and then try prototyping/iterating over those problems.  Write some code, if you're still stuck share it here.

For instance, start by figuring out how to render/scale the background image.  Then figure out how to overlay the line on top, then figure out how to move/erase it.  Then work on performance tuning, etc.

Comment: Since your using a `PictureBox` to present your Bitmap, you don't really need to know anything about the Bitmap itself. Use the `Paint()` event of the `PictureBox` and draw a Line using the provided `e.Graphics.DrawLine()` method, which accepts a `Pen` object. The `Pen` object main properties are `Color` and `Size`. Pick a Color and a Pen size that fits. Add a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with an `Interval` that seems right. On the `Timer.Tick()` event, re-define the position of the Line and call `PictureBox1.Invalidate()`. This will re-paint the Line in your `PictureBox` in a new position.

Comment: Also, with GDI+ (WinForms) you will have a lot of problems with transparency (spoiler: there is no transparency in WinForms), so you better scale a panel width. Or you may dump such pretty old technology and learn WPF/UWP which is on DirectX, so your graphics/animations code will be less painful.

Comment: @vasily.sib  You don't need to handle any transparency for this. Just paint the surface. If you want to draw the line with transparency, this is easily achieved drawing the line using a Pen with semi-transparent color. That's all.

Comment: @Jimi: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It works well and is very stable. My only reservation is that the line scroll is still a bit slow/jerky with high resolution sample pictures. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think the reason for this is that calling PictureBox1.Invalidate() repaints the (potentially high res) sample picture onto the picturebox and if this happens each time the line is drawn there is going to be a performance hit. I have tried invalidating a thin region using Invalidate's Rectangle overload, but this only makes things very slightly faster. Any ideas?

Comment: This all depends on how you're performing the drawing. Since you have some code now, post it here, updating your question. This will immediatly show a problem, if there's one. **Slow**-> I hope you're not *painting* the `Image`. You just need to draw on the Control Device context (provided by the `e.Graphics` object). **Jerky** -> use `e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;` and `e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;` (all set before the actual drawing). Also, try combining with `e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;` for a fast anti alias.

Comment: @Jimi: Thanks for your suggestions. Although they did not improve the speed, they encouraged me to experiment further. By extending the PictureBox class and adding `pe.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor` to `protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)` the line scrolled upto 3 times faster/smoother albeit at the expense of picture quality. I have also added the sample code for the project in the main question as requested.

Comment: I see you got the concept right. Some notes: 1) You don't need to set an InterpolationMode. You need `e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;` Test different `e.Graphics.CompositingQuality` settings. This won't slow the drawing but will increase the quality. Add `e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;` for the maximum quality here. 2) In `timer1_Tick`, calling `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` will **not immediately** cause the re-painting. The code following `Invalidate()` will run **first**. Could be a problem? IDK, but it's better to be aware of this. (...)

Comment: 3) Don't use `new Pen()`. Either enclose it in a `using` block (e.g., `using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White, 2))` ) or use `Pens.White`. But I think you might want to set a Pen.Size, thus the using block is better. If you don't, you're leaking Graphics resource at each drawing and this **will slow down** the process.

Comment: @Jimi: Thanks, I'll use Pens.White instead. Unlike `InterpolationMode`, none of the other suggestions appear to make any discernable difference to either the speed or image in any way (I implemented them in the `OnPaint()` override method of the PictureBox).

Comment: There are many aspects of this than can be adjusted. But I don't see the code that actually performs these adjustments in what you posted. It depends on how well you know your tools. Another note? A timer can be set to 17ms. It will never respect that timing: it's too short in this context. And another one: the maximum number of frames per second in WinForms (unless you can code the redendering in DirectX) is 32 FPS. I could go on.